# Stop IMO messenger asking me to create account

Tags: imo-instant-messenger

I use this to allow me concurrent sessions on my tablet, phone and computer...

...however, everytime I open the app it asks me to create a public profile and verify with my number.

Is there any way I can stop this? I don't really fancy having a public account and I'd prefer them not to have my number (but that's not so much of a big deal).